# how to call next page open using javascript,jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created three tabs initially i want to make the first tab active once i click the save and continue button then only second tab visible.but in my code i click `next-step` next page is not opening...

```
<div class="page-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <header class="section-header">
            <div class="tbl">
                <div class="tbl-row">
                    <div class="tbl-cell">
                        <h2>Company Registration Form</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <section class="tabs-section">
                <div class="tabs-section-nav tabs-section-nav-icons">
                    <div class="tbl">
                        <ul class="nav" role="tablist">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link active" href="#tabs-1-tab-1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="font-icon font-icon-cogwheel"></i>
                                        Company Registration Form
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#tabs-1-tab-2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>
                                        Company Social Network
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#tabs-1-tab-3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
                                    <span class="nav-link-in">
                                        <i class="fa fa-product-hunt"></i>
                                        Company Reference
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div><!--.tabs-section-nav-->
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active show" id="tabs-1-tab-1">
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <section>
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model =>Model.company.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-label semibold control-label" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.CompanyName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtCompanyName", placeholder = "Enter the Company Name" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.CompanyName)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.ShortName, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.ShortName, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtShortName", placeholder = "Enter the Short Name" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.ShortName)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Division, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Division, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtDivision", placeholder = "Enter the Division" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Division)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.company.Email, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.company.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtEmail", placeholder = "Enter your Email" })
                                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.company.Email)
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="SaveCompany" value="Save" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success next-step" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-1-tab-2">
                        <br />
                        <section>
                            <div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.FaceBookID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.FaceBookID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtFaceBookID", placeholder = "Enter the Facebook Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.TwitterID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.TwitterID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtTwitterID", placeholder = "Enter the Twitter Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanySocial.linkedinID, new { @class = "form-label semibold" })
                                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CompanySocial.linkedinID, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "txtlinkedinID", placeholder = "Enter the Linkedin Link" })
                                        </fieldset>
                                    </div>
                                </div><!--.row-->
                            </div>
                        </section>
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Previous" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-primary prev-step " />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="saveSocial" value="Next" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success next-step" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="tabs-1-tab-3">
                        Tab 3
                        <br /><br />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Previous" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-primary prev-step" />
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Finish" class="btn btn-rounded btn-inline btn-success" />
                    </div><!--.tab-pane-->
                </div><!--.tab-content-->
            </section><!--.tabs-section-->
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            //Initialize tooltips
            $('.nav > li a[title]').tooltip();

            //Wizard
            $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function (e) {

                var $target = $(e.target);

                if ($target.parent().hasClass('disabled')) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $(".next-step").click(function (e) {

                var $active = $('.tabs-section .nav li.active');
                $active.next().removeClass('disabled');
                nextTab($active);

            });
            $(".prev-step").click(function (e) {

                var $active = $('.tabs-section .nav li.active');
                prevTab($active);

            });
        });

        function nextTab(elem) {
            $(elem).next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
        }
        function prevTab(elem) {
            $(elem).prev().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]').click();
        }
```

Comment: It's working with me, are you sure bootstrap.js is included in your page ?

Comment: No sir am not using@GabrielGourrat

Comment: You don't want to use it ? have you tested including it ?